# How can I get the parent page title in craft using twig?

Tags: twig, craftcms

Example I have a structure
For all the subpages / child pages in the structure.

I want to access the title of its parent.

The result being that all the level 1 headers have the parent page title displayed as the header

All the children pages have the level 1 (parent page title) as the header

At the moment I am referencing 
`entry.title`

Comment: @HardikSatasiya I guess not, I haven't used octobercms tbh, I've been told that it uses twig so I thought they would be similar! I'll update the tags ;-)

Answer (score 3):

You can access the parent in a struct via `entry.parent` in twig. For example:

```
{% if entry.parent %} 
  <h1>
    {{ entry.parent.title }}:<br>
    <small>{{ entry.title }}</small>
  </h1>
{% else %}
  <h1>{{  entry.title }}</h1>
{% endif %}
```